# How to map the english dictionary to UNSPSC codes?

Tags: search

Is there a db which maps the words from the english dictionary to the UNSPSC codes?(http://www.unspsc.org/)

My problem is the following:
I am building a search system. And the customer searches for 'pencil' and 'pencil sharpeners' are also returned. Each of the returned item has a UNSPSC code associated with it.

So one possible solution would be to search only for those items in the categories the search word belongs to. But this solution would require a mapping from english words to the UNSPSC codes...

Answer (score 1):

Each UNSPSC-code has a title. 'pencil' is part of the following [UNSPSC-codes](http://www.unspsc.org/search-code/default.aspx?CSS=&Type=desc&SS=pencil):

```
44111509    Pen or pencil holders
42295401    Battery operated surgical cautery pencils
60121519    Wax based colored drawing pencils
42295425    Surgical silver nitrate sticks or pencils or crystals
53141611    Fabric markers or fabric pencils or fabric chalk
44121619    Manual pencil sharpener
44121636    Electric pencil sharpener
60121518    Graphite pencils
60121520    Charcoal pencils
44121706    Wooden pencils
44121705    Mechanical pencils
44121702    Pen or pencil sets
44121707    Colored pencils
44121715    Combination pen or pencil
60121531    Pink pencil erasers
60121521    Watercolor pencils
44121714    Pencil or pen grips
```

Is this the list you look for? You could take this values and check if they fit to the UNSPSC-codes from your search.

The complete list of UNSPSC is available at [UNSPSC.org](http://www.unspsc.org/codeset-downloads) (you must be a member or pay $100 per version).